# How to use variables in log4j FileNamePattern

Tags: java, log4j, liferay-7

I am implementing log4j in Liferay (log4j 1.2.17 and LF 7.3).

I tried to set a variable that I can use in the **log4j xml file**.

When I use a logger.info, I use the **PropertyConfigurator** like that:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("instanceId", instanceName);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(p);
```

And in the log4j xml like that:

```
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
           <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${liferay.home}/logs/MY_PROYECT/Portal_${instanceId}/Test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
       </rollingPolicy>
```

And there is only a folder called ***"Portal_"***, the variable **instanceId** doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?